# TFS Build Resets File Version When New Date

Tags: continuous-integration, build-process, versioning

When using TFS 2010 to version builds, the date is included in the build number format (see image below). Versioning works correctly for builds on the same date; the assembly file version increments by one. However, as soon as we build on a new date, the assembly file version starts over at 1.0.0.1.

For example, here are the dates, name of build, and versions on each day:

Sep 7, MyProject_1.0_20120907.1, 1.0.0.**1**
Sep 7, MyProject_1.0_20120907.2, 1.0.0.**2**
Sep 7, MyProject_1.0_20120907.3, 1.0.0.**3**
Sep 8, MyProject_1.0_20120908.1, 1.0.0.**1**  <= Resets to 1.0.0.1 (I want 1.0.0.4)

Is there an easy way to keep the file version incrementing regardless of the date it was built?

[image]

**-- Edit --**

Based on the [macro list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh190719.aspx), it doesn't appear that this is possible. Unless someone can answer otherwise, I'll post an answer that this isn't possible.

Comment: What are you using to version your assemblies?  That Build Versioning section isn't part of the DefaultTemplate.  You might want to see what other values you can specify other than ".B".  Maybe you can do ".BuildID" or something that would use something other than the build revision #

Comment: I already checked for other options (see the link in my edit). BuildID would remain the same for every build since it's the ID of the build type. I think. Hmmmm, maybe I should at least try it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically include the date in my assembly versions, for example: 2.1.1209.1907  this would be the 7th build of the day on Sep 19, 2012 (the 2.1 part I manually control).

Another option is to simply remove the date portion from the Build Number Format, then the revision will increment indefinitely.  E.g. $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Rev:.r)

Comment: Thanks, @Dylan. I'm already doing your second suggestion. It looks like there is no way to increment indefinitely using the default date format.